# Custom View - CheckBoxes not preserving state on rotation

Tags: android

I have a weird problem with a CustomView that holds a CheckBox. When I use multiple of these in a layout, the Checkbox doesn't save the state properly. Either all the CheckBoxes are checked or they are all unchecked after a rotation.

This is an example of the custom view:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val binding = ViewCustomBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(context), this)

    init {
        orientation = HORIZONTAL
    }
}
```

This is the layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:parentTag="android.widget.LinearLayout">

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check_box"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="A Check box" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="12dp" />

</merge>
```

And then in my fragment file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <com.watchqueue.ui.view.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view_0"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.watchqueue.ui.view.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/custom_view_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

When screen orientation changes, Android destroy all existing views and recreate them again, so all unsaved UI changes reset as well. You need to save the view state and restore it again on screen orientation change, or disable orientation change for this view, if it's possible.
Here is the good article about changing orientation: https://medium.com/hootsuite-engineering/handling-orientation-changes-on-android-41a6b62cb43f

Comment: Most Android Views save their own state and CheckBoxes do as well.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? I've tried to reproduce your case in a new simple project also using CustomView and ViewBinding and couldn't, all works fine (checked on API24, 27) @TomislavTurcic

Comment: Yes, I've found the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60623460/android-custom-edit-text-value-is-changed-by-another-custom-edit-text

Comment: Reproduced, just added few more checkboxes. Never faced it before, thanks, good to know.